# Unable to pipe predict() output through filter() to ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm struggling to figure out why I can't use `filter()` on the results
of predict.gam() and then `ggplot()` the subset of predictions. I'm not
sure the prediction step is really part of the problem, but that's what
it takes to trigger the error. Just `filter() %>% ggplot()` with a
dataframe works fine.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)

gam1 <- gam(Petal.Length~s(Petal.Width) + Species, data=iris)

nd <- expand.grid(Petal.Width = seq(0,5,0.05),
                 Species = levels(iris$Species),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
predicted <- predict(gam1,newdata=nd)
predicted <- cbind(predicted,nd)
filter(tbl_df(predicted), Species == "setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Width, y = predicted)) +
  geom_point()

## Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE
```

But:

```
filter(tbl_df(predicted), Species == "setosa")

## Source: local data frame [101 x 3]
## 
##    predicted Petal.Width Species
##    (dbl[10])       (dbl)   (chr)
## 1   1.294574        0.00  setosa
## 2   1.327482        0.05  setosa
## 3   1.360390        0.10  setosa
## 4   1.393365        0.15  setosa
## 5   1.426735        0.20  setosa
## 6   1.460927        0.25  setosa
## 7   1.496477        0.30  setosa
## 8   1.533949        0.35  setosa
## 9   1.573888        0.40  setosa
## 10  1.616810        0.45  setosa
## ..       ...         ...     ...
```

And the problem is `filter()` because:

```
pick <- predicted$Species == "setosa"
ggplot(predicted[pick,],aes(x=Petal.Width, y = predicted)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Nice plot of gam prediction]

I've also tried saving the result of filter to an object and using that directly in `ggplot()` but that has the same error.

Obviously not a crisis, because there's a workaround, but my mental
model of how to use `filter()` is obviously wrong! Any insights much
appreciated.

**Edit:** When I first posted this I was still using R 3.2.3 and was getting warnings from ggplot2 and dplyr. So I upgraded to 3.3.0 and it's still happening.

```
## R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 10586)
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] mgcv_1.8-12   nlme_3.1-127  ggplot2_2.1.0 dplyr_0.4.3  
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      knitr_1.11       magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.2   
##  [5] colorspace_1.2-6 lattice_0.20-33  R6_2.1.1         stringr_1.0.0   
##  [9] plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.3.0      parallel_3.3.0   grid_3.3.0      
## [13] gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        htmltools_0.2.6  lazyeval_0.1.10 
## [17] yaml_2.1.13      assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8     Matrix_1.2-6    
## [21] formatR_1.2      evaluate_0.7.2   rmarkdown_0.9.5  labeling_0.3    
## [25] stringi_1.0-1    scales_0.3.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because your `predict()` call generates a named array, instead of just a numerical vector.

```
class(predicted$predicted)
# [1] "array"
```

The first `filter()` will give you the correct output on the surface, however if you inspect the output you will notice that the column `predicted` is still some sort of nested array.

```
str(filter(tbl_df(predicted), Species == "setosa"))
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   101 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ predicted  : num [1:303(1d)] 1.29 1.33 1.36 1.39 1.43 ...  
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ Petal.Width: num  0 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 ...
 $ Species: chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

In contrast, good old logical subsetting does the job on all dimensions:

```
str(predicted[pick,])
'data.frame':   101 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ predicted  : num [1:101(1d)] 1.29 1.33 1.36 1.39 1.43 ... # Now 101 obs here too
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ Petal.Width: num  0 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 ...
 $ Species    : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

So either you coerce the `predicted` column to numeric:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

predicted %>% mutate(predicted = as.numeric(predicted)) %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = predicted)) +
  geom_point()
```

Or replace `filter()` by `subset()`:

```
predicted %>% 
  subset(Species == "setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = predicted)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Right -- but why does filter() print out the result just fine but fails to pass it to ggplot()? ggplot() doesn't care that the result is an array b/c class(predicted[pick,"predicted"]) is an array and I can make the plot with that.

Comment: Updated with some more info, hope it helps!

Comment: Yes it does -- I believe that's a bug in filter().